# JUnit5 test case calls @Transactional function

Tags: java, spring, transactions, javabeans, aop

Given a TestClass with TestMethod for an integration test (spawning MySQL Testcontainer behind the scenes)

```
@SpringBootTest
public class InsertAnythingIntegrationTest {

  private DoAnythingHandler handler;

  @Autowired
  private AnythingRepository anythingRepository;
  
  @BeforeEach
  void beforeEach() {
    handler = new DoAnythingHandler(anythingRepository);
  }
  @Test
  void handle_shouldAddEntry_givenValidValue() {
      handler.insertSomething(new Entity(x,y,z));
      assertThat(anythingRepository.findAll()).isEqualTo(1);
  }
}
```

and the Handler implementation annotated with @Transactional

```
@Component
public class DoAnythingHandler() {

  @Autowired
  private AnythingRepository anythingRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  @Transactional
  public void insertOrUpdateSomething(Entity entity) {
    var existingEntity = anythingRepository.findById(entity.getId());

    if (existingEntity != null) {
      existingEntity.valueX = entity.x;
      existingEntity.valueY = entity.Y;
      existingEntity.valueZ = entity.Z;
    } else {
      anythingRepository.save(entity);
    }
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new AnyFurtherEventUpdatingDb(entity.X, entity.Y));
  }
}
```

If I run this test, the transaction is never opened since it needs to be called from Bean to Bean to apply the @Transactional annotation.

How can I mock a Bean calling this method in my test case.
I don't want my test case to be @Transactional since I am not able to assert anything. This handler is my UnitOfWork and I want no further abstraction layer whatever in place.

How to approach this?

Comment: So why don't you @Autowire DoAnythingHandler?

Comment: What would be the difference? Then the TestMethod stills not a Bean and the Transactional will not be applied..

Comment: `DoAnythingHandler` would be a bean, and it has its `@Transactional`. So that one will be applied. Because instead of the actual `DoAnythingHandler` a Transactional proxy will be injected. And the invocation will go through that proxy.

Comment: Stanislav is right. Why would the test method have to be a bean? The class under test is, but only if you either auto-wire it or create an instance via the application context's `getBean` method, not if you directly call the constructor, completely circumventing Spring.

Comment: You can directly instantiate the class under test for a unit test, not for an integration test involving the Spring container. But for a unit test to work, you would have to use constructor or setter injection, not private field injection. Protected field injection would, however, work. It seems like nowadays nobody cares about real unit tests anymore. If I were you, I would avoid `@Autowired` on private fields completely, because it makes the class untestable regarding unit tests.

Comment: Hey guys! You are absolutely right! I checked it again and its working now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private DoAnythingHandler handler;
```

did the trick for me.
I thought I tried this before, but maybe I did something wrong before.

Thanks to everyone!